# How do you only allow one of each name in a while loop?

Tags: php, mysql

I am not sure how to word this question, but I have a bunch of codes and I am trying to make an options list so that the user can select which one they want. I am fetching the codes from a query `$acquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM schedules")` and I put it into a while loop.

PHP:

```
<?php
while($ac = mysql_fetch_assoc($acquery))
{
$sel = '';
echo '<option value="'.$ac[code].'" '.$sel.'>'.$ac[fullname].'</option>';
}
?>
```

Since the schedule query has multiples of the same code, it lists the same thing repeatedly. How can I make sure that it lists a unique code ($ac[code] and $ac[fullname] every time?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the question correctly, you can do this by fixing the SQL query to do what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT code, fullname
FROM schedules;
```

Comment: I was unaware of that. Thank you.

Comment: _sidenote: if this did helped you, kindly mark this and accept this as an answer, or an upvote, good day!_